# Is Python's Decimal class variable width?

Tags: python, decimal, precision

In Python, you can have arbitrarily large integers (though it might take up all your memory to store them). With floats on the other hand they will overflow eventually and you lose precision if you try to make one with too many decimal points.

Which one is the [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) class?

Can I have an arbitrary amount of numbers before the decimal point? What about after the decimal point? What are the limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Decimal` has a user-specified precision; you can modify the current context to specify how many decimal digits must be preserved. Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

> Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a user alterable precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as large as needed for a given problem.

That is then followed by an example:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857')
>>> getcontext().prec = 28
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```

You could turn the precision up to 1,000,000 or more if you really needed it, but math will be *slow*. In practice, most problems have a point at which you don't need any more precision; [NASA stops at 16 digits of pi (15 after the decimal) and at the scale of the entire solar system that has an error margin of only an inch or two for any calculations they care about](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/edu/news/2016/3/16/how-many-decimals-of-pi-do-we-really-need/); they'd need more places to the left of the decimal for magnitude, but for most purposes the default precision of 28 is enough, and turning it up to 40 or 50 should cover any use cases relating to numbers from the real world.

The limit isn't to the left *or* the right of the decimal place. It's the total number of digits. So if you have `Decimal(1000000) + Decimal("0.0001")`, with a precision setting of `10` or less, the result will be equal to `Decimal(1000000)` (it may display additional zeroes to match the precision, but the `0.0001` is dropped). The behavior in cases of rounding or overflow is configurable with signals, so it can set flags, or raise exceptions when it occurs. The docs go into this is in greater detail.

Comment: I know it raises an overflow error if your numbers are too large. What determines that limit? Also I don't think the stuff about pi is helpful, float64 has much higher precision and it's evidently useful sometimes.

Comment: @Boris: Whether overflow raises an error is configurable based on signal flags and trap enablers. `float64` actually has ~15.7 decimal digits of precision (`log10(2**52)` IIRC), slightly less than the precision of NASA's value of pi (though that particular pi value does seem to be representable without much rounding), it's not "much higher precision". As I noted, you'd actually need more precision than that for any calculations involving it (there is a reason `Decimal` defaults to 28), but it gives you a rough idea of what precisions are useful.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I deleted it right away because I didn't actually read your entire comment before responding. I really just wanted to ask you to complete your answer with info about the limit to the left of the decimal point, since that was also part of my question